# How do I make a loop start and end with a key press and release?

Tags: java, event-handling, awt, keylistener, event-listener

Here is my code... How can I make it work so that it runs the loop while the user is holding a button and stops when the user releases the button?

```
public void nextPrimeNum()
{
    x = false;
    int b = 2;
    ArrayList<Integer> next = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
    while(x)
    {
        next = factors(b);
        if(next.size()==2)
        {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
        b++;
    }
    System.out.println("End");
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 401)
    {
        x = true;
    }
}
public void keyRealesed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 402)
    {
        x = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You kind of don't, or more to the point you need to be careful how you do it.  A `KeyListener` denotes a graphical user interface, one of the aspects of a GUI is don't want to perform long running or blocking operations in the main GUI thread, like running a loop.  So, either you need to use a `Timer` of some kind or a second `Thread` which can be stopped by flipping a flag

Comment: *"holding a button and stops when the user releases the button"* - ... so do you want a button or do you want key stroke?

Comment: why are the keycode different? they should be the same no?

Comment: I'm new to the event listeners and don't fully understand it yet. The goal however is to be able to hold down any key and have it start printing and when the user releases the key it will stop printing, but not end the program. After the printing has stopped I would still want the program to be able to print if the user holds down a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI and multi-thread programming is inherently difficult.
So, this is as simple as it could be, without violating best practices too much.

You need several things:

- A separate `Thread` for printing primes:
  Its `run` method loops for ever, but pauses when the <kbd>Space</kbd> key is not pressed.
  (see [Defining and Starting a Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for more info)
- A `KeyListener` which will be called from AWT's event dispatch thread:
  The event handling methods are designed to finish fast, so that other events
  (like moving, resizing and closing the frame) still are handled fast.
  (see [How to Write a Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) 
  and [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for more info)
- A visible GUI component (`JFrame`) for adding the `KeyListener`
- Some synchronization between the 2 threads (via `synchronized`, `notify` and `wait`)
  so that the prime-printing starts/continues on `keyPressed`
  and suspends on `keyReleased`
  (see [Guarded Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) for more info)
- Initialize and start the whole GUI by invoking `initGUI`.
  (see [Initial Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more info)

---

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::initGUI);
    }

    private static void initGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JLabel("Press SPACE key for printing primes"));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center on screen
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Main main = new Main();
        frame.addKeyListener(main);
        Thread thread = new Thread(main);
        thread.start();
    }

    private boolean spaceKeyPressed;

    private boolean isPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int n = 2; /**/; n++) {
            while (!spaceKeyPressed) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(); // waits until notify()
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isPrime(n)) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            spaceKeyPressed = true;
            notifyAll(); // cause wait() to finish
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            spaceKeyPressed = false;
            notifyAll(); // cause wait() to finish
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful.

Comment: I don't fully understand how the run method works and the 'SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::initGUI)' . Can you explain how it works in a little more detail.

Comment: @Ben I've added some improvements to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is - it's complicated.  It covers broad topics such as concurrency (in general), GUI development, best practices with the specific API (Swing) which are better covered in more detail by reading through the various tutorials (and experimenting)

- [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)
- [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

The example presents two ways to execute the "loop" (which is presented in the `doInBackground` method of the `CalculateWorker` class).

You can press and hold the `JButton` or press and hold the [kbd]Space[kbd] bar, both will cause the "main loop" to run, updating the `JTextArea` with the results...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea ta;
        private CalculateWorker worker;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            ta = new JTextArea(20, 20);
            ta.setEditable(false);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));

            worker = new CalculateWorker(ta);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Press");
            btn.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("...isRunning = " + worker.isRunning());
                    if (!worker.isRunning()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println("...isPressed = " + btn.getModel().isPressed());
                    System.out.println("...isPaused = " + worker.isPaused());
                    if (btn.getModel().isPressed()) {
                        worker.pause(false);
                    } else {
                        worker.pause(true);
                    }
                }
            });

            add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            worker.execute();

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false), "Space.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true), "Space.pressed");

            am.put("Space.released", new CalculateAction(false, worker));
            am.put("Space.pressed", new CalculateAction(true, worker));
        }

        public class CalculateWorker extends SwingWorker<List<String>, String> {

            private AtomicBoolean run = new AtomicBoolean(true);
            private AtomicBoolean paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);

            private ReentrantLock pausedLocked = new ReentrantLock();
            private Condition pausedCondition = pausedLocked.newCondition();

            private JTextArea ta;

            public CalculateWorker(JTextArea ta) {
                this.ta = ta;
                pause(true);
            }

            public void stop() {
                run.set(false);
                pausedLocked.lock();
                pausedCondition.signalAll();
                pausedLocked.unlock();
            }

            public void pause(boolean pause) {
                paused.set(pause);
                pausedLocked.lock();
                pausedCondition.signalAll();
                pausedLocked.unlock();
            }

            public boolean isPaused() {
                return paused.get();
            }

            public boolean isRunning() {
                return run.get();
            }

            @Override
            protected List<String> doInBackground() throws Exception {
                List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(256);
                long value = 0;
                System.out.println("!! Start running");
                while (run.get()) {
                    while (paused.get()) {
                        System.out.println("!! I'm paused");
                        pausedLocked.lock();
                        try {
                            pausedCondition.await();
                        } finally {
                            pausedLocked.unlock();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("!! Start loop");
                    while (!paused.get() && run.get()) {
                        value++;
                        values.add(Long.toString(value));
                        publish(Long.toString(value));
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    }
                    System.out.println("!! Main loop over");
                }
                System.out.println("!! Run is over");
                return values;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                for (String value : chunks) {
                    ta.append(value);
                    ta.append("\n");
                }
                ta.setCaretPosition(ta.getText().length());
            }

        }

        public class CalculateAction extends AbstractAction {

            private boolean start;
            private CalculateWorker worker;

            public CalculateAction(boolean start, CalculateWorker worker) {
                putValue(NAME, "Calculate");
                this.start = start;
                this.worker = worker;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                worker.pause(start);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

> Is there a simpler solution?

Of course, I always go for the most difficult, hard to understand solutions first (sarcasm)

While it "might" be possible to reduce the complexity, the example presents a number of "best practice" concepts which you would do well to learn and understand.

The solution could also be done differently depending on the API used, so, it's the "simplest" solution for the specific API choice.

> I wanted to do it from the console!

Java can't do that - it's console support is rudimentary at best and doesn't support a concept of "key pressed/released" actions (since it's running in a single thread, it would be impossible for it to do otherwise).

There "are" solutions you might try, but they would require a third party library linked to native binaries to implement, which would (possibly) reduce the number of platforms it would run on